# how to make $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] not to record certain links?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to implement a 'close button' for article page on clicking which the user should be taken back to the category page from where he opened the article from. What I have written to achieve this is the following,

```
<?$back_url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);?>
<a href="<?=$back_url?>"><span class="btn-close">X</span></a>
```

But the problem with this is that it also records pagination urls, so if I use pagination links and then click on this 'close button' it takes me back to previous pagination link instead of going back to the category page.

I don't want `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to record pagination links like [www.foo.bar/article?page_no=1](http://www.foo.bar/article?page_no=1)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you can do about it, because it is the client sending it.

You could use sessions to store some information on where the client came from. Otherwise, just go back to a certain page.

Comment: Is there any other approach to solve this problem? maybe using javascript or something?

Comment: <?$back_url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);?> I want to run this code only once when the user lands on this page, so that its not over-written when pagination links are used. how do I run this code only once on page load and never if paginations are used?

Comment: As I said, use a session and store the value there. If it is not set, set it, if it is set, don't touch it. Check out the documentation on sessions in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php